# (GCP) ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Could not fetch resource: - The SSL key is too large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssl, ssl-certificate, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to create **a self-managed SSL certificate** with **"openssl"** and **"gcloud"** on **Cloud Shell**, **GCP**.

First, I ran this command below to create **"myCert.crt"** and **"myKey.key"**:

```js
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out myCert.crt -keyout myKey.key
```

Second, I ran this command below to create **the self-managed SSL certificate "mycert"** using **"myCert.crt"** and **"myKey.key"**:

```js
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create mycert --certificate=myCert.crt --private-key=myKey.key
```

Finally, I got this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Could not fetch
> resource:
>
> - The SSL key is too large.

Are there any mistakes to my commands?